# Screaming Frog removes custom request headers

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, screaming-frog

We are working on an Angular SPA that uses token-based authentification (our client app gets a token from the server and saves it to localstorage). Then in each request to our API the client adds a special custom header with that token. Our server app authenticates the user by that token and sends the requested data.

The problem is that Screaming Frog, when executing JavaScript code in our client app, does not send our custom headers in AJAX requests. And even more, it does not send the `Referer` header as browsers do.

How to resolve this issue with Screaming Frog?

Comment: Screamingfrog is rather limited. You may have to find another product to achieve your goals.

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately they solved this problem in new version 7.3-beta